# Available servlet containers for Java

Tags: java, servlets, containers

Can anyone tell me if there are more STILL ALIVE servlet containers for Java apart from **Tomcat** (standalone or included in Geronimo, tc Server, etc.), **Jetty**, **Glassfish** (included in Glassfish AS), **Websphere** (included in IBM WSAS), **JBoss** (included in JBoss AS) and **WebLogic** (included in Oracle WAS)?

I know there are many other web server implementations, but I am interested particularly in the servlet containers (aka web containers). I know there used to be many of the lightweight ones but I am not sure if any of them survived in actual working release. I just need to have all of the existings products compared.

Comment: Caucho Resin is also still alive.

Comment: So is [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Sean: I'd say that a project with its latest release over 3 years old probably doesn't count as alive.

Comment: @Michael true, but it still works nicely to make Hudson / Jenkins "runnable"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of servlet containers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container#List_of_Servlet_containers